# Manually insert time stamp into attribute?

Tags: marketing-cloud

For testing purposes I am attempting to insert a timestamp that contains a specific time - such as 2016/09/23 3:55PM - into a subscriber Profile Attribute. But from every method I've tried of adding a specific time it either rejects the date entirely or it ignores the time portion, replacing it with 12:00 AM.

I've been attempting through the UI or with Web Collect but have not had any luck. Does anybody know if it's possible to insert a timestamp into a Profile Attribute field?

Some examples of what I've tried:

2016-09-23T15:55:00Z
2016/09/23 15:55:00
2016/09/23 3:55 PM
2016/09/23 3:55PM
23/09/2016 3:55 PM
23/09/2016 3:55PM

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As an update, SFMC support has informed me that an import is the only way to update a 'Date' field within a list (profile attribute) to contain a specific timestamp. Neither Manually, Web Collect, nor API work. Oh joy....

Comment: This question needs an Upvote... Or we should create an idea for it... It is simply stupid that we cannot insert dates manually.... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

I believe marketing cloud takes the default time settings throughout the account, you can only update, import the time which matches the account time zone settings. 
here is a catch though it accepts account time zone but user profile always overrides the time settings for the account.

Eg: if you have different timezone setup for a user it will accept the time according to user settings.

Comment: Ah - import. How could I forget that obvious method. It's would be nice if a manual method existed, but for testing purposes I can manage with imports.